# When/Where does a user's authentication rappel in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am on the edge to if I should try Firebase for my upcoming project, or stick with the good old SQL db. I have read through the docs, and I think I understand their deal, but there is one thing that's not clear to me; where is the user signed in?

Say I have a sign in page located at:

> mywebsite.com/login.html

After the user has successfully logged in, I wish to redirect the user to the main panel which may be:

> mywebsite.com/main.html

When the user is redirected, is he still signed in, and when does the authentication end? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user will stay signed in across page transitions. The information is retained in local storage of your browser.

The user will stay signed in until you sign them out explicitly, or until an even occurs that requires them to re-authenticate (such as trying to change their password).